# Date Shortcode in Image alt and title tags

Tags: shortcode, title

I am using the following shortcode for year in my Content.

```
function year_shortcode() {
$year = date('Y');
return $year;
}
add_shortcode('year', 'year_shortcode');
```

The same shortcode I used in the image "alt tag and title" which not working

[image]

Any Idea ?

Comment: By default image `alt` tags are never accepting shortcodes. So, where the image alt tag is getting output, you have to manually let it to accept shortcode by embracing it with something like: `echo do_shortcode($alt)`.

Comment: How would I do it that way, Mayeenul Islam? Could you explain more? I'm a beginner... =)

Comment: Also, you're defining a shortcode called `[year]` but you're trying to use `[monthyear]`, which won't work even in places where WordPress *does* parse shortcodes.

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? You'd have to write that as PHP code where you're writing out the <img> tag - you can't use a backend form like there is in the question.

Comment: However you've posted this as an answer on an old question. You might do better asking a new question, but link back here if this is useful context.